# Overloaded method match (can't convert string to int)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get 2 int and 3 strings inserted into the database from a label and 4 tekstboxes.

The Error I'm getting:

> The method Insert has some invalid arguments, the argument cannot convert from string to int.

`lblHidden.Text` and `TextBoxDagnummer.Text` have strings in them but I need to convert them into integers. Do I convert them before the Insert or in the insert and what is the syntax?

**Code behind**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
   Vakinhoudclass.Insert(lblHidden.Text, TextBoxDagnummer.Text, TextBoxHoofdstuk.Text, TextBoxOnderwerp.Text, TextBoxLes.Text);

   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse out the integers from the strings.

Use the [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) or [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to get integers from the inputs.

If the input *cannot* be parsed, `int.Parse` will throw an exception, while `TryParse` will return a `bool` indicating whether it was able to parse or not.

```
int val;

if(int.TryParse(TextBoxDagnummer.Text, out val))
{
  // Parsed OK
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` methods.  For example:

```
int number = int.Parse(TextBoxDagnummer.Text)
Vakinhoudclass.Insert(lblHidden.Text, number, TextBoxHoofdstuk.Text, TextBoxOnderwerp.Text, TextBoxLes.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like it would be best to convert to an integer before the database insert. This way you can catch any error that might occur before talking to the database at all.

Here is an easy way to convert a string to an integer:

```
Convert.ToInt32(lblHidden.text)
```

I'd also suggest surrounding this with a try-catch block

```
            try
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(lblHidden.Text);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //an error occured
            }
```

Comment: Instead of an expensive `try{}catch{}` (in case of an exception) you should be using `int.TryParse`, avoiding the possibility of an exception to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback on my question so far but I'm getting the same errors:
- The best overloaded method match for "Vakinhoudclass.Insert(int,int,string,string,string)" has some invalid arguments.
- Argument 1 and 2 cannot convert from "string" to "int"

Using this code now:

int number = int.Parse(TextBoxDagnummer.Text);
int number2 = int.Parse(lblHidden.Text);
Vakinhoudclass.InsertVakInhoud(lblHidden.Text, TextBoxDagnummer.Text, TextBoxHoofdstuk.Text, TextBoxOnderwerp.Text, TextBoxLes.Text);
GridView1.DataBind();

(also tried with the Covert method)

**EDIT**

Whoops I see what I did wrong, need to paste them into the insert function like this:
int number = int.Parse(lblHidden.Text);
int number2 = int.Parse(TextBoxDagnummer.Text);
Vakinhoudclass.InsertVakInhoud(number, number2, TextBoxHoofdstuk.Text, TextBoxOnderwerp.Text, TextBoxLes.Text);
GridView1.DataBind();